# how do I use a firestore / firebase callable function when my user is not registered?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4, google-cloud-functions, itunes-app

Usually in iOS, you login and auth() to firebase with your user email and password, to use callable functions. Behind the scenes the firebase framework is managing your token. However as iTunes developers know, often your application is rejected when forcing users to register (and thereafter, login): [App rejected because asking user registration (Guideline 5.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788841/app-rejected-because-asking-user-registration-guideline-5-1-1)

I was wondering if and how I could **securely** call a firebase 'Callable' function in swift 4, or if I could just insert data directly into the firebase database, **securely**, without having any login authentication and no authorization - because I need to let users 'skip' registering on the welcome page to fulfill iTunes app requirements.

thanks

Comment: You don't need to be authenticated to invoke a callable.  It just won't provide the function a UID.  Are you observing something different?

Comment: I haven't tried yet - I was just wondering if it is possible and secure.

Comment: Allowing a non-authenticated user to call your functions means you have little way to control the calls. Whether that is secure depends on what your function does.

Comment: Yes, you will have to define what "secure" means in your case.